# Грамматически правильное ли название?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Академия Юного Бизнеса - грамматически правильное название? Понимаю, что бизнес не может быть юным/старым, но в контексте названия звучит круто, даже фигурируя в рекламе.

Answer (score 2):

Академия юного бизнеса - вам действительно не режет слух? Это не то что неправильно, но и очень уродливо.

Академия юношеского бизнеса, может? Академия молодежного бизнеса?

И еще: в русском языке в названиях, состоящих из нескольких слов, с заглавной буквы пишется только первое слово (кроме имен собственных, разумеется).

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически не правильно - "Академия юного бизнеса".

И лексически не правильно (и звучит странно). Правильно: "Академия юных бизнесменов".

`Юный` употребительно по отношению к человеку, а не ко всем абстрактным понятиям. Вот как ужасно звучит в других случаях: юное хобби, юное занятие, юное животное, юный телевизор. Тоже самое и с бизнесом, только тут оно чуть меньше выражено.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97524/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).

Comment: Да это неправильная ссылка. [Вот](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97523/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd) правильная. И вообще почему создалось два разных чата?

Answer (score 0):

К грамматике претензий нет. Вот со смыслом надо бы разобраться.

> Понимаю, что бизнес не может быть юным/старым, но в контексте названия
>   звучит круто, даже фигурируя в рекламе.

Как раз - может. Новый, только начавший развиваться. 
Правда, совсем непонятно, что имели в виду авторы такого названия. 
То ли школу начинающих бизнесменов, то ли своего рода "переподготовку" под новые, "юные" направления... Ну или вообще - возраст своих "академиков".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97565/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus----).

Answer (score 0):

Не вызывающее в части грамматики название не даёт понять статус и специализацию учреждения, но содержит некую долю агрессии, эпатажа. Претензия на краткость — единственное, что в нём можно отметить и сохранить.

Вижу необходимость в обобщении понятий по иной схеме, а именно, по типу конструкции «Бизнес-академия Юных».